# Not able to create tables.

Tags: octobercms

I'm new to October, and I came across an issue which I wasn't able to solve. When I create a plugin from the command line, and run **plugin:refresh** the tables in the database are not being created.

The version.yaml is correct as per documentation. Here are the contents of the files.
Plugin/Mejlak/PropertyExtender/Updates/create_extras_table.php

```
<?php namespace Mejlak\Propertyextender\Updates;

use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

class CreateExtrasTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mejlak_propertyextender_extras', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('mejlak_propertyextender_extras');
    }
}
```

And here is the version.yaml

```
1.0.1: 
    - 'First version of propertyextender'
    - create_extras_table.php
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Your directories are lowercase? for instance:  `plugins/mejlak/propertyextender/updates/`

Answer (score 2):

Change your version.yaml to:

```
1.0.1: First version of propertyextender
1.0.2: 
  - create tables
  - create_extras_table.php
```

I have no idea why commands do not work on first plugin version. And you also have to put **- create tables** before the list of create_tablename_table.php files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess as per @OsDev suggested there may be issue with directory names.

you give us path for update is

> Plugin/Mejlak/PropertyExtender/Updates/create_extras_table.php

so in this case you can correct some folder names

I am not sure but all your folder name is starting with capital letters, in october cms all are written in small so your path should be

> **plugin/mejlak/propertyextender/updates**/create_extras_table.php

and yes in namespace its correct so no need to change there

> namespace **Mejlak\Propertyextender\Updates**

then give it a try, if still its not working please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the plugin refresh command you have tried to run?

`php artisan plugin:refresh Mejlak.Propertyextender`

Answer (score -1):

No need to create migration-file/table manually. With 'https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder' you can create a fully functional plugin scaffold in a matter of minutes.

1) install the plugin
2) Go to Builder-> Create plugin-> create
[image]
3) Add table from Database
[image]
4) Save and Apply migration file
[image]
Your plugin has been created with a table now.